# how to check a ui-slider is disabled or not

Tags: jquery-ui-slider, disabled-control

I need to know how to check a ui-slider is disabled or not.
I have tried with

```
$('#slider_price').is(":disabled")
```

But i always get "false" even if the slider is disabled or enabled.

Please help me and thanks in adavance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can try like this

```
$( "#slider_price" ).slider( "enable" );
```

or

var isDisabled = $( "#slider_price" ).slider( "option", "disabled" );

Comment: hi i need to check its status either "disabled" or "enabled" ??

Comment: just add if condition if($( "#slider_price" ).slider( "option", "disabled" ))console.log("true") else console.log("false")